# django admin foreign key to file field and many to many field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model `Teacher` which has following data:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(Thumbnail)

class Thumbnail(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
```

Here I want to relate all the `thumbnail` in my project to `Thumbnail` field. In my admin it shows me a dropdown of `thumbnail` while I want to add the `thumbnail` from admin.

Is it possible that I can upload from admin too?

Also what can I do in the case like :

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    thumbnail = models.ManyToManyField(Thumbnail)
```

If I want to add multiple Images.
The only issue I am having is on admin side. Client side can be handles from regular forms.

Need suggestions and Ideas